# Dplyr group_by when a variable has to take one of multiple values for the same variable

Tags: r, dplyr

```
data_2019q1 %>% 
    group_by(UF, V2007, V2010) %>% 
    summarize(meanIncome = mean(VD4020, na.rm= TRUE))
```

is what im trying to do, but i want it to show meanIncome for people who live in UF = X or Y or Z as a single value

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

In the `group_by`, modify the 'UF' with `replace` to a single value i.e. "Other"

```
library(dplyr)
data_2019q1 %>%
     group_by(UF = replace(UF, UF %in% c("X", "Y", "Z"), "Other"), 
              V2007, V2010) %>%
     summarise(meanIncome = mean(VD4020, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or another option is `fct_collapse` from `forcats`

```
library(forcats)
data_2019q1 %>%
     group_by(UF = fct_collapse(UF, Other = c("X", "Y", "Z")),
          V2007, V2010) %>%
     summarise(meanIncome = mean(VD4020, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: This is working very nicely, but how would i do more replaces? I tried a lot of options but couldnt. As in :  (UF, UF %in% c("X", "Y", "Z"), "Group1") but also (UF, UF %in% c("A", "B", "C"), "Group2")